# How to Fetch shared secret key for auto-renewable inapp purchase?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I am implementing Auto-renewable InApp purchase. As far as my knowledge the `SHARED_SECRET_KEY` that is begin provided on iTunes connect is for individual user account. And that is being used when `verifying receipt` In that case I can't use it as static `#Define` var.

I also didn't find it in `SKPaymentTransaction` object.

How can i fetch it for individual user as we get receipt_data for particular user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, as far as I know, SHARED_SECRET_KEY is not used for individual user account, but for the application itself.

You need to verify receipt when transaction Status is SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased with the active transaction (SKPaymentTransaction) in payment queue.

When I was implementing inapp purchasing, my main confusion was to fetch information about a particular user just like you. I am saving information about my purchases, so at startup I can refresh about the user. Also restoring is another method I can suggest for supporting multiple devices (up to 5) of a user.

Comment: Will affect InApp if I am not implementing `Restoring` to my app??

Comment: No, as far as I experience, InApp can work smoothly without restoring.